# Easiest "daytime" service client in Python?

Tags: python, networking, tcp

What's the easiest way to write a daytime client in Python?

And if there's more data of unknown size but still plain text - how do I read until the server closes the connection?

Comment: Homework?  Please label homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: No, not homework. Just needed a small quick TCP one-line reader.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "time.nist.gov"
port = 13
s.connect((host,port))
while True:
    data = s.recv(10000)
    if data:
        print data
    else:
        break

s.close()
```

Comment: and amazingly, still works in 2021. The more advanced RFC-868 Time / rdate protocol seems to have been dropped.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
from contextlib import closing as C

address = "time.nist.gov", socket.getservbyname('daytime')

with C(socket.create_connection(address, timeout=2)) as conn:
    with C(conn.makefile()) as f:
         print f.read(),
```

The solution:

- cleanly finalizes resources
- may eat your memory if the service misbehaves; though [rfc 867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc867) says:

  > The daytime should be just one line.

Here's a [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#auto2) version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from twisted.internet  import protocol, reactor

class EchoClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = lambda _: protocol.ConsumerToProtocolAdapter(sys.stdout)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print reason.value
        reactor.stop()

host, port = "time.nist.gov", 13
reactor.connectTCP(host, port, EchoClientFactory(), timeout=2)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Twisted - it will take some time to get the concept, but it rocks!

Start with tutorials http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html - first two should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, but a little much overhead don't you think?

Comment: It will pay off in the long run if you intend to stuff your client with features.