# DetermineThe Correct Time

Tags: python, windows

How can I get the correct UTM time regardless of whether the user has set their Windows OS date and time correctly?

I have done some tests where I set my Windows clock to a different time and run the exact same code. Each time it outputs the Windows clock time. I am looking for code to always output the correct UTM time.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

print time()
print datetime.utcnow()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664295/ntp-client-in-python

Comment: Doesn't print datetime.utcnow() solve the issue?

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun No it doesn't like I explained above. Try it; run my code, then change your windows time to 2 of so hour's different and run the code again. It prints out 2 different times. So datetime is relying on windows to know the time then convert it to utc.

Comment: stdlib only solution [Easiest “daytime” service client in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1873214/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use NTP module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/

Example from the site:

```
import ntplib
from time import ctime
c = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = c.request('europe.pool.ntp.org', version=3)
ctime(response.tx_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this solution require the user to be connected to the internet? I guess the solution posted is 'use the internet to determine the correct time'? Is there any local way of determining the correct time?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Unfortunately, I don't think there exists a way to reliably determine system time without using the internet.

Comment: @Mack: No, there is no local way of determining the actual time.  (I can't imagine how you think that might work...)  There are of course other possible external sources apart from the internet: a cellphone network, GPS, etc., but the internet is the only one that most computers will support.  Keep in mind that none of these solutions are foolproof, a determined user will be able to bypass them and feed you a false time.